# Holomorphic Functions and Cauchy Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Show that if $f$ is holomorphic in an annulus $V={r<|z-c|<R}$ then the integral

$$\int_{|z-a|=\rho}fdz$$ has the same value for all $\rho$, $r<\rho<R$.

**My approach:** Suppose a function $f(z)$ holomorphic on the annulus  $r <|z −c| < R$ has two Laurent series:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(z-c\right)^{n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(z-c\right)^{n}$$

Multiply both sides with $\left(z-c\right)^{-k-1}$, where k is an arbitrary integer, and integrate on a path γ inside the annulus,

$$\oint_{\gamma}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(z-c\right)^{n-k-1}\mathrm{d}z=\oint_{\gamma}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(z-c\right)^{n-k-1}\mathrm{d}z$$

The series converges uniformly on $\epsilon\leq|z-c|\leq R-\epsilon$, where ε is a positive number small enough for γ to be contained in the constricted closed annulus, so the integration and summation can be interchanged. Substituting the identity

$$\oint_{\gamma}(z-c)^{n-k-1}dz=2\pi i\delta_{nk}$$

into the summation yields

$$a_k=b_k$$

Hence the Laurent series is unique.

Can anyone assist help explain why $$\oint_{\gamma}(z-c)^{n-k-1}dz=2\pi i\delta_{nk}$$ is the case to me?

Comment: Do you know about Laurent series?

Comment: @zhw... am not too familiar with it. Kindly assist in explaining that to me.

Comment: @zhw, I just modified the problem. Can you explain the latter part to me?

Comment: Let me ask another question: Do you know Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @zhw. I am familiar with Cauchy Theorem. How does that relate to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider a contour that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: that was the assumption I used and the considered the annulus to be the space between the two circles. But the later part of my proof got me confused. I need someone to help explain that or give a better proof.

Comment: You want the circles to have radii $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ where $r < \rho_1 < \rho_2 < R$.  Since $f$ is analytic in a set containing the "C" and the integrals over the straight segments cancel, $\oint_{|z| = \rho_1} f(z) \; dz - \oint_{|z|=\rho_2} f(z)\; dz = 0$ by  Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: This certainly helps alot. So how does one make conclusions from what you stated?

Comment: If the difference between the two integrals is $0$, the integrals are equal, which is exactly what you want.